# load blob pdf in syncfusion javascript ejpdfviewer

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

i have this code im trying to load blob pdf , whever it successfully open in a new tab but i want this pdf to be loaded in syncfusion ejpdfviewer , any suggestions

html
`<div id="iframe"></div>`

javascript

````
                xhr.open('POST', '/MifosX/Reports/RunReportPDF');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(reportrequestviewmodel));
                xhr.responseType = "blob";
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    let stateCode = 0;
                    console.log("readyState", this.readyState);
                    console.log("status", this.status);
                    if (this.readyState === 4) {
                        this.onreadystatechange = null;
                        if (this.status === 200) {

                            var file = new Blob([xhr.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                            window.open(fileURL);
                            console.log(fileURL);

                            $("#iframe").ejPdfViewer({ serviceUrl: fileURL, interactionMode: 1 });

                            console.log(xhr.response);
                        } else {
                            alert(this.statusText);
                            stateCode = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    return stateCode;```
````

Answer (score 1):

PDF viewer do not have support to load the PDF document from the URL directly. However, you can load the PDF document by converting the URL to base64 string using the client-side documentPath API in the sample level.

Please find the code snippet for the same from the below,

```
$("#pdfviewer").ejPdfViewer({ serviceUrl: '../api/pdfviewer/', documentpath:base64data ,pdfService: ej.PdfViewer.PdfService.Local });
```

Note:

- We can  provide the Pdf document name/path of base64string of the PDF
  Viewer in the documetPath API during control initialization.
- We can  also load the PDF document dynamically in PDF Viewer using
  load()    API.
- serviceUrl property in the PDF Viewer is used to map the
  controller.(our PDF Viewer is both client and server side oriented).

We have created a simple sample to load the PDF document using documentPath and shared the same in the following location,

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PdfViewerSamples_(5)1344181241

Getting started UG link : https://help.syncfusion.com/js/pdfviewer/getting-started

Please find the below KB for reference, 
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8737/how-to-load-a-pdf-document-from-url-into-pdf-viewer-from-client-side

Thanks,

Akshaya